# А Parser3 от ArtLebedev до сих пор кто-нибудь использует?

Tags: парсер

Не знаю, где ещё такой вопрос задать.

Некоторое время назад (этак 2002), [Parser2/Parser3](http://parser.ru/) были очень полулярные языки в России, вроде даже популярнее PHP, но вроде как это было до нашествия Ruby и Python.

Что-нибудь изменилось?  Языки Parser2 / Parser3 до сих пор где-нибудь используют?  (Я вот смотрю что здесь на *ru* даже такого тага нет!)  Или даже *Студия Лебедева* перешла на альтернативные технологии?  Если да, то очень интересно — какие.

Comment: Насколько я помню, даже в 2002 эти языки не были популярными в России. Это была внутренняя разработка Студии, практически недокументированная. В 2002-м году подавляющее количество проектов делали на PHP, довольно много продолжали делать на Perl, ну и корпорации делали на ASP (старом, классическом, не .NET).

Comment: Я сам писал и на Parser2, и на Parser3 — всё было отчётливо документировано на parser.ru (хотя код Parser2 так и не выложили, но такого особо и не обещали), было каждый день очень много пользователей и сообщений на форуме, бывший newyork.ru тоже вроде был написан на Парсере.  Многие хостинги специально рекламировали поддержку Парсера в то время.  А сейчас у них даже на главной странице parser.ru про каких-то Апач рассказывают!

Comment: У нас, видимо, разные представления об отчётливом документировании. Можно просто сравнить документацию по Вашей ссылке и документацию, например, на сайте http://php.net. Вторая мне кажется гораздо более проработанной. Вероятно, какие-то разработчики были и на Парсере, но массовым это явление не было никогда. В частности, я не помню за всё это время ни единой вакансии, где требовалось бы знание Парсера.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, документацию и даже сравнивать не получится — на php-дот-net ничего толкового действительно нет, в то время как на http://www.parser.ru/docs/lang/ всё написано по-русски ясным языком (а не корявым машинным переводом), можно даже себе было сразу моментально скачать в формате Windows Help CHM (было очень полезно во времена dialup).  И это так ещё было более десяти лет тому назад.  Я в то время ещё учился, но точно помню, что и вакансии тоже были (вне Студии).

Comment: хорошо, я Вас понял. Разделить Вашу точку зрения не могу, и, видимо, мои воспоминания кардинально отличаются от Ваших. http://php.net всегда читал на английском языке, и ни разу на русском.

Comment: @cnst: «хорошо» и «на русском языке» это совсем несвязанные понятия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иногда ещё, встречается на проектах которые были изначально на нём написаны и переписать руки не доходят, либо в качестве рудиментов на проектах которые не до конца переписаны. Но эпизодически натыкаюсь на эту технологию на просторах рунета. Но новых проектов давно не видел